# Will there be something like Apple's Quicklook included by default?

Tags: unity, 11.04

You know... to compete with Mac OS X. Or will we have to install 'gloobus' manually?

Answer (score 3):

Short answer: Yes, you will have to install it manually.

Long answer: There is already a thumbnailing (preview-like) feature for Nautilus. Gloobus seems like a good project, but can be obstructive (especially for new users) when you want to open a file with its designated editor/viewer/whatever. It just seems superfluous to me.

Comment: Quicklook was created, wasn't it, because Programs like Adobe Reader take ages to load. The only thing I can think of where it would make sense is with OpenOffice documents, the only program left I think that takes an appreciable amount of time to load. For everything else, I agree it'd be superfluous.